# which is more efficient, simple or nested condition using IF()

Tags: php, function

I'm newbie, and just want to asking about programming stuff. I hope you guys help me getting understand :)

which is more efficient in coding and performance between this two function?
first function using nested condition, and second function using simple condition,
which is better to be implemented?

```
function optionOne()
{
    $a = getData();
    $return = array();

    if ($a === false) {
        $return['error'] = true;
    } else {
        $b = getValue();
        if ($b === false) {
            $return['error'] = true;
        } else {
            $c = getVar();
            if ($c === false) {
                $return['error'] = true;
            } else {
                $return['error'] = false;
                $return['message'] = 'congrat!';
            }
        }
    }

    return $return;
}

function optionTwo()
{
    $return = array();

    $a = getData();
    if ($a === false) {
        $return['error'] = true;
        return $return;
    }

    $b = getValue();
    if ($b === false) {
        $return['error'] = true;
        return $return;
    }

    $c = getVar();
    if ($c === false) {
        $return['error'] = true;
        return $return;
    } else {
        $return['error'] = false;
        $return['message'] = 'congrat!';
    }

    return $return;
}
```

thank you before guys,

Comment: Better to use `switch` if you can. But according to your question, `nested condition` would be good.

Comment: "efficient in coding" -- what do you mean? "performance" -- do not bother yourself with it in this case (the difference so small that you could not measure the difference between properly). Take care about readability. Second one is better.

Comment: thank you, the measure for my case is readability?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function option()
{
 $return=array();
 $return['error'] = true;

 switch(getData()){

 case false:
 return $return;
 break;

 case true:
 if(getValue()==false){return $return;}
 else{
 if(getVar()==false){return $return;}
 else{
 $return['error'] = false;
 $return['message'] = 'congrat!';}
 }
 break;

 default:
 return 'getData() return null value';
 break;
 }

}
```

i was tried to applied the switch method to your function, as one of your option too

Comment: thanks for accepted my answer, actually there are still so much of way to increase performance in code, just depend on how condition is.

Comment: Was fixed some mistake

Answer (score 0):

A neater option would be to make the 3 functions throw an exception when there's an error instead of returning boolean false. That's what exceptions are for anyway. Then in your function you can just wrap the calls in a try-catch block.

```
function option {
  $return = array();
  try {
    $a = getData();
    $b = getValue();
    $c = getVar();

    $return['error'] = false;
    $return['message'] = 'congrat!';
  } catch(Exception e) {
    $return['error'] = true;
  }

  return $return;
}
```

Comment: by your code, how do I check $a, $b, $c?, or just let them without check the return value of them?

Comment: The try and catch blocks do the checking. So your getData(), getValue() and getVar() should throw an Exception instead of return boolean false when something is wrong. If any of them throws an exception, the code flow in your option() function will jump to the catch block. Read more about exception here: http://php.net/exception